# Solving $x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + y\frac{\partial u}{\partial y }=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I want to solve the differential equation $$x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + y\frac{\partial u}{\partial y }=1$$

with the initial condition $u(1,y)=y.$

I'm very unfamiliar with possible methods to solve pde's. A method I found ([link](http://staff.um.edu.mt/jmus1/PDE.pdf)) would go as follows:

$$\dot{x}=x,\;\;\;\;x(0)=1\\\dot{y}=y,\;\;\;\; y(0)=y\\\dot{u}=1,\;\;\;\;u(0)=1$$
but the second equation doesn't seem possible. Can this method be applied to solve the equation or I need a new one?

Another question: In the link (page 2) they wrote $x(t)=0$, and after $x(t)=e^t$ as a solution, but how can that be when $e^t$ is nonzero for every $t$?

Comment: I guess you mean the method of characteristics ? Yes that would be appropriate here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a simpler way. Set $\alpha=\ln x$, $\beta=\ln y$, then the equation becomes
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial \alpha}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial \beta}=1.$$
Next make another change of variables $z_{\pm}=\alpha\pm\beta$, after which the equation reduces to
$$\frac{\partial u\,}{\partial z_+}=\frac12,$$
with the obvious general solution $u=\frac{z_+}{2}+F(z_-)$, where $F$ denotes an arbitrary function. Hence
$$u(x,y)=\frac{\ln xy}{2}+F\left(\ln\frac{x}{y}\right).$$
It remains to use the initial condition to determine the form of $F$; and one finds $F(z)=\frac{z}{2}+e^{-z}$.

Comment: Very nice indeed, +1!

Answer (score 2):

This is known as the method of characteristics. First it helps to distinguish $u(1,s)=s$, so that the second equation reads $\dot{y}=y$ with $y(0)=s$. Afterall it's not that $y(0)=y$, that makes no sense. Rather, we make $y(0)=s$ a free parameter which then ensures $u(1,s)=s$. This is also where you need to set up the $u$ equation correctly, it should read $\dot{u}=1$ with $u(0)=u(x(0),y(0))=s$.

The first equation gives you $x=e^t$, the second gives $y=se^t$ and the third gives $u=t+s$. This gives $u(x,y)=\ln(x)+y/x$.

Now check, $u_x=1/x-y/x^2$ and $u_y=1/x$, so $xu_x+yu_y=1$ as required. Finally, $u(1,y)=y$.

Answer (score 1):

I use [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics) method usually,
i.e. we get $$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{du}{1},$$
which implies $$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y}\quad\text{and}\quad\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{du}{1},$$
so $x=ky$ where k is constant and $y=ce^{u}$, hence I get the characteristic equation $$f\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)=\frac{y}{e^u}\tag{1}.$$

Apply initial condition $u(1,y)=y$, i.e. $x=1$, $y=y$, $u=y$.

We get $f\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)=\frac{1}{e^y} $,hence $f(t)=e^{-\frac{1}{t}}$ by putting $t=\frac{1}{y}$,apply it in eqn($1$) we get $e^{-\frac{y}{x}}=\frac{y}{e^u}$, from here find $u(x,y)$.

But of course it helps only to find one solution.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{x\,\partiald{\,{\rm u}}{x} + y\,\partiald{\,{\rm u}}{y}=1:\
     {\large ?}\,,\qquad \,{\rm u}\pars{1,y} = y}$.

---

In this particular case it's convenient to 'shift' the solution by '$\,\ln\pars{x}\,$' in order to have an homogeneous equation: 
\begin{align}
x\,\partiald{\rm u}{x} + y\,\partiald{\rm u}{y}=1\quad\imp\quad
x\,\partiald{\bracks{{\rm u} - \ln\pars{x}}}{x}
+y\,\partiald{\bracks{{\rm u} - \ln\pars{x}}}{y}=0
\end{align}

---

So, we'll use the *Characteristics Method*:
$$
\dot{x}=x\,,\quad\dot{y}=y\qquad\imp\quad\totald{y}{x}={y \over x}\quad\imp\quad
{y \over x}=\mbox{constant}
$$

---

The form of the solution is given in terms of an arbitrary function , for the time being, $\fermi\pars{x,y}$ of $y/x$. $\fermi\pars{x,y}$ is deduced by imposing the initial condition $\,{\rm u}\pars{1,y}=y$:
$$
\,{\rm u}\pars{x,y} - \ln\pars{x}=\fermi\pars{y \over x}\quad\imp\quad
y=\,{\rm u}\pars{1,y}=\fermi\pars{y}
$$

---

which is replaced in the previously found general solution
$\,{\rm u}\pars{x,y} = \ln\pars{x} + \fermi\pars{y \over x}$:
$$
\color{#66f}{\large\,{\rm u}\pars{x,y}}
=\color{#66f}{\large\ln\pars{x} + {y \over x}}
$$